# Check if value is first occurence in result set

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to check if the result from a query is the first occurence in the line.

These are my results from a MySQL dBase:

```
1
1
1
1
1
0
0
0
0
0
```

I am showing them with:

```
while($resource = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
     echo '<h3>'.$resource['status'].'</h3>'; 
}
```

I would like to insert a horizontal line before the first occurence of the first '0'-result, Like:

```
1
1
1
<hr> <<-- right there 
0
0
0
```

Tried everything but nothing gets close to what I want. Anyone an idea?

Comment: Do NOT use `mysql_*` it has been removed and it will not work anymore, use `PDO` [link](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or `mysqli` [link](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$id = false;
while($resource = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    echo '<h3>'.$resource['status'].'</h3>'; 
    if($resource['status'] !== $id){
       $id = $resource['status'];
       echo '<hr>';
    }        
}
```

Comment: This would spit out an HR after every new entry

Comment: Yes, the idea is to not spit out an HR after every new entry. Can't seem to fix it.

Comment: This will only display a HR if the value is different than the one before

Comment: But does someone have a neat solution for this?

Comment: Thank you Eric! I was a little off because of all this talking. Super thanks for your answer! It works indeed!

Comment: OK, folks, let's lay off the personal insults. I've cleaned things up here, but please try to stay civil.